# Detecting if I am in an exit handler in C++

Tags: c++

I would like to know if I am in an `atexit()` handler. I'm looking for the moral equivalent of `std::uncaught_exceptions()` for `exit()` calls.

I want to do this so I can have the destructors in my static objects behave one way when my `main()` function returns, and another way when `exit()` is called.

I could add a call to `atexit()` that sets a bool I inspect, but that runs into ordering issues. For example, this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Setter {
    static void set_in_at_exit() { in_at_exit = true; std::cout << "setting\n";}
    Setter() { std::cout << "constructor\n"; atexit(set_in_at_exit); }
    static bool in_at_exit;
};

bool Setter::in_at_exit = false;

struct A {
    A() { static Setter s; }
    ~A() { if (Setter::in_at_exit) {
            std::cout << "in at exit\n";
        }
    std::cout << "My destructor\n"; }
};

A a;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
constructor
My destructor
setting
```

Which is not what I want. The destructor doesn't know it is in an exit handler.

Comment: Why don't you simply set `in_at_exit` before `return 0` in main? Seems like an awful lot of code to achieve something as simple.

Comment: Because I'm providing a library that is used by mains I do not control.

Comment: `main() function returns, and another way when exit()` These are equivalent. You are looking for portable solution? (I guess you _could_ inspect callstack somehow, because with `main` returning it _could_ be one greater, but that's luck).

Comment: Then I suppose this won't be possible with just standard C++ without having clients of your library change their mains or call a different exit, as the ordering of global initialization and destruction is undefined.

Comment: Also, this seems like a bit of an XY problem. Why do you need to do that? Maybe you can achieve your greater goal some other way?

Comment: Since you have a library, require that the library user calls your library `startup();` before using it, and calls your library `shutdown();` before `main` completes so the library can gracefully release its resources.  Then your library can track if it is before startup, or while active, or after shutdown.

Answer (score 4):

> [basic.start.main]
> A return statement (8.6.3) in `main` has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with
> automatic storage duration) **and calling `std::exit`** with the return value as the argument. If control flows off the end of the compound-statement of main, the effect is equivalent to a return with operand `0`

So no, you cannot distinguish between the two situations unless you somehow instrument all explicit calls to `exit` *or* all `return` statements and the last line before the closing brace in `main`.